# Trying to set MaskRe to accept symbols

Tags: javascript, extjs, playframework

I have a DateField and I want to limit the users input to only numbers and symbols (/ . -). I am using the maskRe function, but do not know how to indicate to include symbols. Right now it is only accepting numbers.

```
 maskRe: /[0-9]/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[maskRe](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe) (follow the link for the official documentation) refers to a regular expression which is tested against each character the user tries to enter and filters characters which do not match the pattern.

You will need to extend your regular expression to allow the characters you mentioned:

```
maskRe: /[0-9\/.-]/
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option for accept date for user is DatePicker. that accept only date as require. 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.field.DatePicker